# Why doesn't my theme show up in LightDm Greeter?

Tags: themes, lightdm, xfce

I am using axiomd theme on my computer (xubuntu) but when I change the theme in /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf it doesn't change the theme of the login screen.

Going through the LightDM GTK+ Greeter: settings doesn't work either. It only shows 4 themes I can choose from, even though I have around 20 themes in /usr/share/themes.

Answer (score 0):

The themes have to be complete gtk themes; not just windows or icon themes, nor metacity themes.

Look in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d for a customization file. I usually takes precedence over /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but editing the file in /usr/share/... did not have any effect. Also the axiomd is a complete gtk theme.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, LightDM might not have access to your theme. Chmoding the theme folder worked for me.